# How to get dropdown selected value in render control of repeatercontrol in c#

Tags: c#

I am doing a c# web app.I have a repeater control.A drop down is placed in the repeater control.i want to mail what ever is there in the repeater control.so i am using repeatercontrol.rendercontrol.but i am getting dropdown as normal.i want the dropdown value which user selected in the mail.pls help.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a loop in the repeaterItems and for each item you get the ddl as following:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < repeater.Items.Count; i++)
 {                              
   DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList) repeater.Items[i].FindControl("DropDownId");

 }
```

Comment: Sir,I am not asking about how to get the drop down list selected value from repeater control.i am asking the drop down selected value when repeater.rendercontrol method is used.that means in mail how i should get when render control method is used

Comment: i mean if a drop down having yes or no in repeater control,if user selects yes,in mail i need to get yes as selected value when i use render control.but i am getting drop down with yes or no.